# app.use express doesn't load assets folder

Tags: express

**hello**
i want to make an express project, but i have a problem
My folder looks like that:

```
> assets
> node_modules
> views
   > pages
      > index.ejs
> index.js
> routes.js
```

In routes.js i have only this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.render('pages/index');
});
```

My index.js:

```
 global.express = require('express');
global.app = express();

global.port = 80;
global.livereload = require('express-reload')
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
require('./routes.js');



app.listen(port);

console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
```

And when i access localhost/assets i got `Cannot GET /assets/`

Comment: What is in your assets folder that you wanna access with `localhost/assets` ?

Comment: @yousoumar css/js files

Comment: You have to be precise when you wanna access a folder that does not contain an index file, like so : `localhost:8080/assets/css/styles.css`. And add the port in your url.

Comment: @yousoumar Cannot GET /assets/css/index.css

Comment: Did you add the port in the url ?

Comment: @yousoumar http://localhost:8080/assets/css/index.css

Comment: Are you using port 8080 ? Mine was juste for example.

Comment: @yousoumar yes, i put 8080 port instead of 80 and still doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, I had to see the port you are using in the first place and just tel you to use this url `localhost:8080/assets/css/index.css`. Having port 80 or 8080 is not the problem. I pasted a possible response below. Check out !

Answer (score 1):

i fixed with app.use(express.static('assets'))